# multiple docker-compose.override files for building multiple ENV docker images

Tags: c#, .net, docker, docker-compose

In my .net core 2 application, I have files

- appsettings.Development.json
- appsettings.Staging.json

Application is dockerized and I have a `docker-compose.yml` with corresponding docker-compose.override.yml.

Inside `docker-compose.override.yml` I have ports and `Staging` related things using `ENV` variables

```
serviceone:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://0.0.0.0:5500
    ports:
      - "5500:5500"
```

This works perfectly so far, cause I had only one dockerize env (`Staging`), `Development` one I use only for debugging locally. Now I want to introduce support for `QA` by having another docker image for QA.

I'll put `appsettings.QA.json` in the solution and *my question is*:

> Should I create another `docker-compose.overrideSTAGING.yml` (or what's the naming convention here) and how will docker-compose know about it's existence?

Currently, I'm using `docker-compose up --build` from cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I create another docker-compose.overrideSTAGING.yml (or what's the naming convention here) and how will docker-compose know about it's existence?

Compose only includes `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose.override.yml` files, by default.

You should use the `-f` option to include files with different names.
See [explanation here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/).